# how do I find out what "pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp" is aliased to without googling

Tags: python, pandas

**Train of thoughts:**
how do we check datatypes in pandas?
many ways, `isinstance()`, `type()`, `sr.dtype`, `df.dtypes` etc

the next step is, what's the exact word I should put in your source code to do this:
`type(myvar) == <what do I put in here?>`

ok, the simpliest way to find out is to try it out:

```
type(myvar)
>> pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

so, the following is good and all, but that's quite a mouthful,
`type(myvar) == pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

**Question**
I happen to know that `type(myvar) == pandas.Timestamp` would work as well for this particular data type. I would like to know a general way of finding out if and what python types are aliased to something shorter.